# laravel how can deduct user points

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i am running a scheduler when user point reach 5000p i want to automatically deduct the point , i am using this package to handle user points https://github.com/ansezz/laravel-gamify
the point deduction  isnt working kindly assist

```
public function handle()
{
    $users = User::with('points')->get();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->achieved_points >= 5000) {
                $user->user->achieved_points - $user->achieved_points;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share Kernel.php and what time you have set for running this scheduler?
Have you checked your cronjob is running??

Comment: you are not saving the model. Then, $user->user??? Why? The code is incorrect. Can you fix it before asking?

Comment: The body of your `if` statement doesn't contain any executed code, just an expression.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should use the package specific method : [undoPoint()](https://github.com/ansezz/laravel-gamify#undo-a-given-point).

You can try something like :

```php
public function handle()
{
    $users = User::has('points', '>=', 5000)->get();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        foreach ($user->points as $point) {
            $user->undoPoint($point);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've also update your query to only include user with more than 5000p, see [Querying Relathionship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Comment: its not working

Comment: Can you explain @caroMedia ? Got an error ? Just no effect ?

Comment: the error i am getting is user->achivived point on null

Answer (score 0):

```
public function handle()
{
    $users = User::with('points')->get();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->achieved_points >= 5000) {
            $user->user->achieved_points->decrement($user->achieved_points);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).